# Confuse with variable scope for while and for loop(C programming)

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, while-loop, scope

Today while i was coding , I encounter something which I didn't expect it to happen in this way.Below is just an example code for the problem.

**The Code 1**

```
while(true)
{
 int i = 1;

 printf("This is %d\n" , i);
 ++i;
 if(i == 10)
   break;
}
```

**The Code 2**

```
for(int i = 1 ; ; i++)
{
 printf("This is %d\n" , i);
 if(i == 10)
    break;
}
```

**The Question :**

1.)The first code would causes infinite loop while the latter is not.

2.)I don't understand , there's a standard mention variable declare inside while loop can be accessed by any statement inside the while loop , but why the `if()` can't access the value of variable i while the latter can??

*Thanks for spending time reading my question*

Comment: sorry i forgot to indent the code just now

Comment: Nope it does , i've try using C language and PHP both yield the same result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
for(int i = 1 ; ; i++)
{
    printf("This is %d\n" , i);
    if (i == 10)
        break;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        printf("This is %d\n" , i);
        if (i == 10)
            break;
        i++;
    }
}
```

I.e., the `int i = 1` part is executed *before* the first iteration of the `for`-loop. `for` introduces an implicit extra scope block holding any variables declared in the `X` of `for (X;Y;Z)`.

Answer (score 6):

C has the notion of block scopes.  A variable declared in a given scope has a lifetime equivalent to that scope.  In the `while` loop case that means there is one `i` variable for every iteration of the loop.  Every time the loop restarts it creates a new `i` and sets it's value to `1`.  The `i++` only evaluates once on that instance and hence it will never reach `10` and will indeed infinite loop.

The first code sample can be fixed by simply moving the `i` before the `while loop`.

```
int i = 1;
while (true) {
  printf("This is %d\n" , i);
  ++i;
  if(i == 10)
    break;
}
```

Now `i` is declared in the outer scope and hence there will be one `i` for all of the iterations of the `while` loop.

The `for` loop case works for nearly the same reason.  The iteration variable declared in a `for` loop is defined once for all iterations of the loop.

Comment: Yes, C has block scope, but since C99 there's an implicit extra block introduced by `for`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying , i started to understand the logic behind this :), really thank you for all the precious answers given

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your while loop, not only are you declaring i, you're initializing it.  So on every loop iteration, i is reset to 1, causing your infinite loop.

The for loop initializes i = 1 first, before starting the loop, so it's more like writing a while loop like this:

```
int i = 1;
while (true)
{
    printf("This is %d\n" , i);
    if (i == 10) break;
    i++;
}
```